# Conditional Component Rendering using UseState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements, rendering

I have a form in a page, when the user inputs the name of a new student and clicks submit, I want the content of that component (the form) to be completely replaced by the submitted name. How can I achieve this (Replace the form with the list onsubmit)?

I have read that I can use conditional rendering to toggle components, but it's not really clear to me how i can apply it here.

**StudentListResult.Jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import StudentForm from "./StudentForm";
import StudentList from "./StudentList";

const StudentListResult = () => {
  const [newStudent, setNewStudent] = useState("");
  const [students, setStudentsList] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <StudentForm
          newStudent={newStudent}
          setNewStudent={setNewStudent}
          students={students}
          setStudentsList={setStudentsList}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <StudentList students={students} setStudentsList={setStudentsList} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default StudentListResult;
```

**StudentListForm**

```
import React from "react";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

const StudentListForm = ({
  newStudent,
  setNewStudent,
  students,
  setStudentsList,
}) => {
  const addStudent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setStudentsList([...students, { id: uuidv4(), name: newStudent }]);
    setNewStudent("");
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={addStudent}>
      <div>
        <input
          value={newStudent}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Student Name"
          onChange={(e) => setNewStudent(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default StudentListForm;
```

**StudentList.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const StudentList = ({ students = [], setStudentsList }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {students.map((student) => (
        <ul key={student.id}>
          <li>
            <p>{student.name}</p>
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
export default StudentList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to show the form if not submitted and show the list if submitted? You can add a piece of state called `submitted` and do simple [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator).

```
const StudentListResult = () => {
  const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false)

  return (
    {submitted ? <StudentList /> : <StudentListForm />}
  );
};
```

And then in your `addStudent` function, set `submitted`.

```
const addStudent = (event) => {
  // ...
  setSubmitted(true)
}
```

Comment: This works, but how can I implement this so that when I submit, I would see the previously submitted student names and not just one name? Currently, when I submit,  I only see just one student's name, I don't see the previously submitted names as I was before with this line ```setStudentsList([...students, { id: uuidv4(), name: newStudent }]);``` in ```StudentListForm```.

Comment: You should still have that line in your `addStudent` function. I simplified the code in my answer (that's why there's a `// ...`). You should keep all the code you currently have in `addStudent`, just add the `setSubmitted(true)` line at the end. Then it should work, afaict.

Answer (score 1):

If you want change form and list visibility state, you need pass custom function to form component:

**StudentListResult.jsx**:

```
const StudentListResult = () => {
  const [newStudent, setNewStudent] = useState("");
  const [students, setStudentsList] = useState([]);
  const [getFormSubmitted, setFormSubmitted] = useState(false);

  const setCompletedForm = () => {
    setFormSubmitted(!getFormSubmitted);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {getFormSubmitted ? (
        <div>
          <StudentList students={students} setStudentsList={setStudentsList} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <StudentForm
            newStudent={newStudent}
            setNewStudent={setNewStudent}
            students={students}
            setStudentsList={setStudentsList}
            onComplete={setCompletedForm}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then call this function if form is submitted and all conditions is true

**StudentListForm.tsx:**

```
const StudentListForm = ({
  newStudent,
  setNewStudent,
  students,
  setStudentsList,
  onComplete
}) => {
  const addStudent = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setStudentsList([...students, { id: uuidv4(), name: newStudent }]);
    setNewStudent("");
    onComplete();
  };
```

Comment: This works, but how can I implement this so that when I submit, I would see the previously submitted student names and not just one name? Currently, when I submit,  I only see just one student's name, I don't see the previously submitted names as I was before with this line ```setStudentsList([...students, { id: uuidv4(), name: newStudent }]);``` in ```StudentListForm```.

Comment: @Tini No problems with multiple student objects 
[see this link for example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-lovelace-3mzvsw?file=/src/studentListResult.jsx)